# Ho do you hide / highlight rows based on the value cells

Tags: excel

I am new to excel and want to programmatically do two things.

1. Hide entire row if Code = 0
2. Set background and border to all cells in rows if columns I - O = 0

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your sheet generated by something? (VBA/Formula etc or is it manually edited) Hiding the rows is easy enough but unhiding them if you need to add more records can be a pain

Comment: All products are pulled from another sheet by VLookup. On the other sheet products are pasted in. The quantity might changed based on if the company adds products. Im very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code in a new module (VBA Editor, Insert->Module).

```
Public Sub ToggleRows()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Row As Long
Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace with the name of your worksheet

' Get Row Number of last Row
Row = Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + Sheet.UsedRange.Row - 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

While Row > 1 ' (exclude header row)
    ' Hide/Unhide Row depending on value in Column A
    Sheet.Rows(Row).EntireRow.Hidden = IIf(Sheet.Cells(Row, "A").Value = 0, True, False)
    Row = Row - 1
Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

After copying it you should have a "ToggleRows" macro in the list when you press the Macros button in the Developer tab.

If you wanted the macro to run automatically, you need to add a few more lines of code.

Open the code module for your worksheet and put the following

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
ToggleRows
End Sub
```

For the second part of your question, you should be able to use Conditional Formatting.

There are many ways you can do it, one way is:
Select Columns I->O and select *New Rule* from the conditional formatting menu, and then select *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*

Enter a formula (example below) and then specify the formatting.

`=IF(SUM(INDIRECT("I"&ROW()&":O"&ROW()))=0,TRUE,FALSE)`

If Sum of Cells I-O equals 0, apply the formatting, otherwise dont.